# Automation tool for Angular Application?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wanted to automate angular based application. So am doing POC for that, And my first preference will be `Selenium WebDriver` if not then any other tool. I heard and read about Protractor, And `Protractor` will be the best tool for angular based application. But I don't have any idea about protractor. And I have a silly question-

> 1 - Why selenium does not support angular based application? if yes how we can achieve by using selenium ?
>   2 - Why Protractor will be best choice for Angular based application? If yes please give me some strong points.

So I want to be clear about these two question with some real time scenario. And Please do comment if is there any blogs or page where I can find these details. Please suggest me some good points which can help me to take the decision.

Thanks All, Please do help!.

Comment: I think you should read the protractor homepage - https://www.protractortest.org/#/. Protractor is built on top of webdriverjs targetting angular apps. There is a library for angular apps using java - https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver

Comment: @gowtham, 
1, Yes selenium supports angular based application with the help of ngWebdrivver, previously there were no support from selenium, to handle angular based locators, Now we can use selenium ngwebdriver (javascript based library) to automate angular applications

2, Ofcourse protractor will be the best choice to automate angular applications, as it has angular based selectors like (ng-model, nd-repeat, ng-buttonText, Id, ClassName, ng-binding. etc.....) and also can perform well with both angular and non-angular pages with the protractor methods, It has default wait 11 seconds.

Comment: @Parthi , Well Thanks, Do we have any documentation about ngWebDriver, how to use and where to use those new methods.

Comment: And one more question up to what version of **angular-Js** can **ngWebdriver** supports?

Comment: There are no much documentation and no online help for ngWebdriver, as it is new and many of them are not aware about it, I suggest you to go with protractor,

Comment: ngWebdriver - https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver

Answer (score 1):

For angular based web applications, I'd choose protractor over Selenium since protractor handles asynchronous calls perfectly while in selenium, you need to specify explicit waits for the calls to get completed. It also handles angular objects better than selenium.

I've documented it here : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GDFc77rex-Fqf1B8wosrxk1DePe4qt7-HzpZxyzXzeI/

As to why you should use protractor over selenium, I've put it on a blog post : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/functional-test-automation-using-protractor-selenium-ranganatha/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion and for your documents.

Answer (score 0):

I created a java library on the top of selenium which should work with angular applications also. It has an implicit waiting mechanism and can be found here: https://github.com/gartenkralle/web-ui-automation

You can extend it for your own needs by forking the sources.

Comment: Thanks you for your support. Will try this library. Thanks again.